# How to compile PMD with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, pmd

I have obtained PMD (source code analyzer tool) tool's source code files and I had made some changes. But the problem is when I made these changes on eclipse I couldn't find a way to compile the PMD source code files. Any help would be nice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is, if you modified PMD through its source code and you want use it, you must realize that PMD is also a maven project. Therefore maven projects helps you compile and install your modified your program.

In detail, when you compile your PMD, it create test class and a jar file. If you replace those files with the pmd.bin version (not pmd.src version), you will be able to use your modified PMD project.

Answer (score 0):

rulesets/favorites.xml             basic

Comment: That wasn't what I was looking for. I compiled it pmd's source files with maven and it worked.